# containsValue() not working with DocumentSnapshot from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read a particular field within Firebase and depending on what the field says it will determine whether a boolean is true or not. After doing research I've only found the containsValue() method as a solution for that, however, it's not working for me even when I follow the examples to a T. I get the error: "The method 'containsValue' isn't defined for the type 'Function'." Am I missing something?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class CProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CProfilePageState createState() => _CProfilePageState();
}

class _CProfilePageState extends State<CProfilePage> {
  bool admin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getBool();
      setState(() {});
  }

  getBool() async{
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('All Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get();
    if(snapShot.exists){
      if(snapShot.data.containsValue("Y")){
        admin = true;

      }
      else{
        admin = false;
      }
    }
    return admin;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        toolbarHeight: 50.0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [ admin == true ?
              compProfileCard() : driverProfileCard(),
              profileImage(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try with:

```
snapShot.data.data().containsValue("Y")
```

or:

```
snapShot.data().containsValue("Y")
```

instead of:

```
snapShot.data.containsValue("Y")
```

?

Comment: For future reference - you can also search on containsKey()

Comment: I'm getting `error: The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Function'` on `document.data.containsKey('file_name')`... any suggestions?

Comment: @genericUser "data()" use data as a function, not a variable

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan `(document.data() as Map<String,dynamic>).containsKey('field_name');` solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108767/12695188

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentSnapshot.data` is not a property, but a [method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html). You need to call it like this: `snapShot.data()`.