# Cannot check containsKey on DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if a field exists in my `documentSnapshot`.

My code:

```
document.data.containsKey('field_name')
```

But I'm getting:

> error: The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
(document.data() as Map<String,dynamic>).containsKey('field_name');
```

Comment: This works! Can you explain a little bit why this works? Thanks!

Comment: This is called casting. Because contains key is a method on Maps. But the firebase object is still considered dynamic. Although the keys are there, but eobiect itself is not known to be a map.

Comment: And using the .() On data, is actually executing the function that unravels the map from the snapshot. Without using data(), you're just trying to read keys on something that points to a map, but is not actually a map, merely a reference to the real map.This is what I think, not 100% sure of the technicality.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the data as a function, like this `.data()`

Comment: Not working :\ `error: The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`